# Window "capture" application, upon unexpected termination, allows captured windows to disappear, how can I prevent/fix this issue?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, winapi, user32

I have an application (C# + WPF) that attempts to wrest control of the graphical interface of any process passed to it as an input and resize/reposition for my own purposes.

It does its job rather well, I think. Upon expected termination (the base class inherits from IDisposable) the "captured" process is released - its parent is set to the original, its windowstyle is reset, etc. etc.

In fact, on testing, I can capture, release, recapture, and so on, the same process as *many* times as I want with no issues.

However, upon unexpected termination (say another process forcefully kills it), the process never regains its graphical interface! I can tell its still running but I can never set that process back to its original state.

It almost seems like the process doesn't respond to window-based Win32 API calls that set specific window features anymore (for example, I can get information with GetParent, GetWindowThreadProcessId, etc but calling ShowWindow or related results in nothing).

<strike>Any suggestions on why this is happening? I'm guessing that since I set the parent of the process to my WPF application (which then unexpectedly closes) it causes some issue in trying to recover the initial interface?</strike>

[This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) is why it's happening (or, at least, an indication of why I had so much difficulty finding the issue out on my own); can I recover from it? And, if so, how?

Edit -

[IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) makes a good point in the comments, question adjusted to make better sense for this particular application.

Comment: This question (or its moral equivalents) keep coming at a constant rate. What you are trying to do is not a supported scenario. Please read [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)

Comment: That's a very good point and gets right to the root of my question. Great find. 

I guess my question shouldn't be how to "prevent it" but rather, can I recover from it *without killing the process* and how?

Comment: There really isn't much to recover, as you *already* are in unsupported territory, the moment you call `SetParent` with window handles owned by different threads. This isn't explicitly called out in the documentation, but doing this calls [AttachThreadInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-attachthreadinput) for you. From there, it goes downhill, e.g. [AttachThreadInput is like taking two threads and pooling their money into a joint bank account \[...\]](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130619-00/?p=4043).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I've gotten my answer; so, for the sake of completeness I'll post what I've gotten here in case anyone else has a similar issue.

According to the information provided by [IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) in [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130619-00/?p=4043) (with more context in the comments), it seems that what I'm trying to do here (assign a new parent cross-process) is essentially unsupported behavior.

**My Solution:**

Recovering (at least at the point that I'm talking about - i.e. unexpected crashes or exits) probably isn't feasible, as we've already gone off the end in undetermined/unknown behavior. So I've decided to go for the preventative route.

Our current project already makes use of the [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) framework to communicate across servers/processes so I'm going to "refine" our shutdown procedure a bit for my portion of the program to allow it to exit more gracefully.

In the case of a *truely* unexpected termination, I'm still at a loss. I *could* just restart the processes (actually services with a console output, in our case, but w/e) but my application is just a GUI/Interface and isn't very important when compared to the function these processes serve. I may make some sort of semaphore file that indicates whether a successful shutdown occurs and branch my code off so that it indicates that the processes are no longer visible until the next time they're restarted.